# Can I grant privileges to a role without specifying an object?

Tags: oracle, security, oracle-11g

I am trying to create a role to simplify granting a set of privileges that I often give to users. I am wondering if there is any way to grant these privileges on only the objects owned by their schema without knowing what the schema name will be ahead of time?

For instance, I want to assign the role `student_access` to the users `JOE` and `MARY` without having to specify what tables or procedures they have these privileges on. They should have all privileges that the role grants on all objects owned by their schema.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system privileges that relate to the object types (`CREATE TABLE`, `VIEW`, ...) can be divided in two groups:

- Those that lack the keyword `ANY` are only effective on the user's own schema.
- Those with the keyword `ANY` (`DROP ANY TABLE`, `EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE`, ...) are effective on all schemas. Consequently, you should restrict the `ANY` privileges to administrative users.

If you grant an object type privilege (without `ANY`) such as `CREATE TABLE` to a role, all users of this role will be able to assert this privilege on their own schema. Consequently you can grant these privileges to a role and the users will inherit such rights (on their own schema) when they are granted the role.

Comment: Perfect. All of the examples of the syntax I was able to find contained the `ON some_table` portion of the command. I have successfully granted privileges to a role without specifying a target object with `GRANT connect TO student_access;`

Comment: `CONNECT` is a built-in role; you didn't grant privileges to `student_access` as much as you granted a role through which `student_access` inherits `connect`'s privileges.

Comment: `CONNECT` was a bad example on my part. I am trying to grant system privileges (I think that's right) to a role so that instead of typing `GRANT CONNECT, CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE... to username;` I can just type `GRANT student_access TO username;` Is that not what this is doing?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle, unlike DB2, doesn't support `GRANT SELECT ON some_schema TO some_role` or `GRANT SELECT ON some_schema TO some_user`.  It's up to you to ensure that the privileges you want granted are granted; I find it a best practice to save the grants against schema objects with the DDL I used to define those objects.